# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long and basic Authentication

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

I have webspace, hosted at a german provider (its name could be understood as »2«) and added an SSL-Certificate to the domain. The domain points to a subdirectory in webspace. The subdirectory is protected using basic Authentication with the .htaccess file like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthName "Hallo!"
AuthUserFile <path>/.users
Require valid-user
```

Everthing works fine over `http`, but with `https` I get this error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to <domain>.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. 
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

That is firefox, but all other browsers do not work too.

Is the Authentication what breakes the https connection? If yes, what could I use instead?

Thanks in ahead!

Comment: It isn't the Basic authentication, but rather indicative of an SSL misconfiguration in the webserver. How and what depends on the actual webserver.

Comment: thank you, thought its my failure. I going to contact the provider.